# What is 1.5 pair cable?

Tags: cables

I've come across a spec for **1.5 pair cable** and wondered if it's just three conductor cable. It would be nice to have this confirmed, as well as have an explanation for why it's called in such a roundabout manner. Is the word *pair* a specific terminology in this context which somehow conveys something "(un)shielded 3-conductor cable" does not?

Comment: Link? It may be 1 twisted pair and a loose conductor, which would have some uses. "Pair" does sort of imply twisted to improve balance.

Comment: I think it is just a special case of a multipair cable. So in n-pair you substitute `n` with `1.5`. The difference with 3-conductor cable would be that in 1.5-pair, you can have a twisted pair bundled separately from the additional conductor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's 1 twisted pair for a differential signal such as RS-485 and a single wire for a ground connection between the transmitter and receiver(s). You can see an example with a bit more explanation on page 5 of this: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla292a/slla292a.pdf?ts=1606836400144